# Play- why PersistenceException is occured?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, playframework

I want to update/edit my information on database. But when I am trying to do so, it shows error:

> Execution exception
>
> PersistenceException occured :
>   org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to
>   persist: models.User

My model is:

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model implements RoleHolder {
    @Required
    @Unique
    @MaxSize(120)
    @Email
    public String email;

    @Required
    @Unique
    @MaxSize(15)
    @MinSize(4)
    @Match(value = "^\\w*$", message = "Not a valid username")
    public String name;

    @Required
    @MaxSize(15)
    @MinSize(4)
    @Match(value = "[^=]*", message = "Not a valid password")
    @Password
    public String password;

    @Transient
    @Equals(value = "password", message = "Password doesn't match")
    @Password
    public String confirmPassword;

    @MaxSize(100)
    public String displayName;

    @Required
    @ManyToOne
    public Role role;

    @Required
    @ManyToOne
    public SchoolInformation school;

    @Required
    @ManyToOne
    public Ngo ngo;

    /* GEO-location Hierarchy */
    @ManyToOne
    public GeoDivision geoDivision;
    @ManyToOne
    public GeoDistrict geoDistrict;
    @ManyToOne
    public GeoUpazilla geoUpazilla;

    /**
     * @param email
     * @param password
     */
    public User(String email, String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        /* this.geoPSUs = new TreeSet<GeoPSU>(); */
    }

    /**
     * @param email
     * @param password
     * @param name
     */
    public User(String email, String password, String name) {
        this(email, password);
        this.name = name;
    }

    public User(String email, String password, String name, Role role) {
        this(email, password, name);
        this.role = role;
    }

    // From RoleHolder Interface
    @Override
    public List<? extends Role> getRoles() {
        List<Role> list = new ArrayList<Role>();
        list.add(this.role);
        return list;
    }

    /**
     * Authenticate.
     *
     * @param username
     *            the username
     * @param password
     *            the password
     * @return the user
     */
    public static User authenticate(String username, String password) {
        return User.find("byNameAndPassword", username, Crypto.passwordHash(password, HashType.SHA512)).first();
    }

    /**
     * Find User by name
     */
    public static User findByName(String name) {
        return User.find("byName", name).first();
    }

    /**
     * Before save a User
     */
    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    public void beforeSave() {
        updatePassword();
    }

    /**
     * Update password by its hash value
     */
    private void updatePassword() {
        Logger.info("password set for " + this);
        this.password = Crypto.passwordHash(this.password, HashType.SHA512);
    }

    /**
     * Return list of User with given role
     */
    public static List<User> getRoleUser(Role role) {
        return User.find("role = ?", role).fetch();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.id + " " + this.name + " " + this.email + " ";
    }

    public static User findByLogin(String username) {
        return User.find("byName", username).first();
    }

    public static List<User> findFsByDsUser(long dsId) {
        return User.find("byDs_id", dsId).fetch();
    }

    public static List<User> findEnumeratorByFsUser(long fsId) {
        return User.find("byFs_id", fsId).fetch();
    }

    public static List<User> findAllEnumeratorUsers() {
        return User.find("byRole_id", 4).fetch();
    }

    public boolean isAdmin() {
        return role.equals(Role.getAdminRole());
    }

    public boolean isEnumerator() {
        return role.equals(Role.getEnumeratorRole());
    }

    /**
     * Return parent User. From Edmis hierarchy, M&H for M&C, M&C for DM, DM for
     * FF, otherwise null
     */
    public User getParentUser() {
        User parentUser = null;
        return parentUser;
    }

    public static List<User> getChildEnumerators(User loggedInUser) {
        List<User> enumList = new ArrayList<User>();
        List<User> users = User.findAll();

        for (User user : users) {
            if (user.getParentUser().equals(loggedInUser)
                    || user.getParentUser().getParentUser().equals(loggedInUser)) {
                enumList.add(user);
            }
        }
        return enumList;
    }

    public void update(Long id) {

        String qString = null ;
        Connection conn = play.db.DB.getConnection();
        ResultSet rs = null;
    }
}
```

My controller is:

```
@ExternalRestrictions("Edit User")
   public static void edit(Long id) {

        User user = User.findById(id);
        flash("user", "" + user.id);
        notFoundIfNull(user, "user not found");
        user.password = null;
        List<Role> roles = Role.findAll();
        List<SchoolInformation> schoolList = SchoolInformation.find("approavedStatus = ? ", "Approved").fetch();
        List<Ngo> ngoList = Ngo.findAll();

        List<GeoDivision> geoDivisionList = GeoDivision.findAll();
        List<GeoDistrict> geoDistrictList = GeoDistrict.findAll();
        List<GeoUpazilla> geoUpazillaList = GeoUpazilla.findAll();
        render(user,schoolList,ngoList, roles,geoDivisionList,geoDistrictList,geoUpazillaList);
    }

    @ExternalRestrictions("Edit User")
   public static void submit(@Valid User user) {
        Logger.info("flashUserId in Submit: " + flash.get("user"));
        validation.valid(user);
        if(validation.hasErrors() && flash.get("user") == null) {
            List<Role> roles = Role.findAll();
            Logger.info("hasError");
            render("@edit", user, roles);
        }
        if(flash.get("user") != null){
            User editedUser = User.findById(Long.parseLong(flash.get("user")));
            editedUser.name = user.name;
            editedUser.id = user.id;
            //Logger.info("updated username : " + editedUser.name);
            editedUser.displayName = user.displayName;
            editedUser.email = user.email;
            editedUser.role.id = user.role.id;
            editedUser.school.id = user.school.id;
            editedUser.ngo.id = user.ngo.id;
            editedUser.geoDivision.id = user.geoDivision.id;
            editedUser.geoDistrict.id = user.geoDistrict.id;
            editedUser.geoUpazilla.id = user.geoUpazilla.id;
            Logger.info("name: " + editedUser.name + " displayname: " + editedUser.displayName + " email: " + editedUser.email + " role: " + editedUser.role.id + " ngoId: " + editedUser.ngo.id + " geoDivisionId: " 
            + editedUser.geoDivision.id + " geoDistrictId: "+ editedUser.geoDistrict.id + " geoUpazilaId: "+ editedUser.geoUpazilla.id);
            editedUser.save();
        }
        else {
            user.save();
            create();
        }

        flash.success("Record saved successfully.");
        list("0");
    }
```

I have to change ID because , I want to update the information of table. Suppose, this is the current condition:

[image]

Then,I want to update Upazilla like this:

[image]

Then it shows error.

where is the problem? 
[image]

Comment: Don't change the identifier field id of a persisted entity

Comment: I can't understand.please explain it

Comment: In your submit method you set `editedUser.id = user.id`. Remove that line.

Comment: no,change. same error @JackFlamp

Comment: Ok Looks like you are changing id Fields of more entities. Dont do that. Remove All lines where you change ids

Comment: But I have to change ID , @JackFlamp

Comment: Why? Id field is used by Hibernate and DB to find the correct row. I can't imagine why you would need to do that.

Comment: I have added two screenshots,I think u can understand

Comment: If I want to edit/update upazilla or others,it shows error.because, previous upazilla ID is 4 and now changed upazilla ID is 1

Comment: My guess would be that there are two different Fields and you are changing the wrong one. Id vs userId or something like that?

Comment: nope,there is only one field

Comment: Id in your image would be 7 and userId 22222. Thats my guess. Maybe someone else knows

Comment: If you are using hibernate/jpa you have to fetch the entity before updating it because it needs to `attach` the object on the context.

Comment: How can I do it @pedroct92 ? give me example please

Comment: You would query the user by its id and take the fields from the object that has the changes and set them on the one you queried from the database. https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2404032

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by changing my controller like this:

```
 @ExternalRestrictions("Edit User")
   public static void submit(@Valid models.User user) {


        Logger.info("flashUserId in Submit: " + flash.get("user") + " and user id is : " + user.id);
        validation.valid(user);
        if(validation.hasErrors() && flash.get("user") == null) {
            List<Role> roles = Role.findAll();
            Logger.info("hasError");

            render("@edit", user, roles);
        }

        Logger.info ("id: "+ user.geoUpazilla.id);   
        if(flash.get("user") != null){

            User editedUser = User.findById(Long.parseLong(flash.get("user")));

            editedUser.name = user.name;
            editedUser.displayName = user.displayName;
            editedUser.email = user.email;
            editedUser.role = user.role;
            editedUser.school= user.school;
            editedUser.ngo = user.ngo;
            editedUser.geoDivision = user.geoDivision;
            editedUser.geoDistrict = user.geoDistrict;
            editedUser.geoUpazilla = user.geoUpazilla;

            Logger.info("id : " + editedUser.id + " name: " + editedUser.name + " displayname: " + editedUser.displayName + " email: " + editedUser.email + " role: " + editedUser.role.id + " ngoId: " + editedUser.ngo.id + " geoDivisionId: " 
            + editedUser.geoDivision.id + " geoDistrictId: "+ editedUser.geoDistrict.id + " geoUpazilaId: "+ editedUser.geoUpazilla.id);

            editedUser.save();


        }
        else {
            user.save();
            create();
        }

        flash.success("Record saved successfully.");
        list("0");
    }
```